# Why did Vishnu violate Vrinda, to defeat Jalandhar?

Tags: hindu

I personaly don't think he violated Vrinda as per current violation defination. I believe he violated her per ancient defination by siting with her.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This seems as if it might work on our sister site [hinduism.se]. Be sure to take their tour and read up in their help centre *before* posting there, perhaps citing the verse you might be referring to. That being stated, your post may work here to if you add clarity about the nature and circumstances of Vishnu's act to Vrinda, and clarify how it might be a violation (presumably to Tulasi) and what ancient tradition you might be referring to.

Answer (score -2):

That's why you should not rely on English translations. There is a saying, why to read the English translations made by the foreigners when we have Indian languages. English language doesn't contain exact technical meaning for each and every Sanskrit /Hindi/Telugu word. English language cannot define the technicality of Hindi /Telugu/Sanskrit words and I will prove you that the r@pe you're accusing did not happen. It was said that, Vrinda's Pativrata should be broken. But Pativrata in Sanskrit is not same as Chastity or Modesty in English.

Now let us debunk this claim with proper Sanskrit slokas. The essence of this story is about the origin of Tulasi plant or Holy Basil plant.

She married asura named (Jalandhar) and due to her Pativrata dharma, her husband has become invincible and started torturing the three realms. The only way to kill him was to destroy the Pativrata Dharma of Vrinda Devi.

Here comes the problem, the English translators translated Pativrata (Pati + Vrata) as Chastity which is wrong.

This is what is mentioned in Shiva Purana, Yuddha khanda, 22nd chapter, 50th sloka (Sanskrit )

Parvati uvacha

Tainaiva darsitah pantha buddasta tvam hi

Tatsatri pativratam dharmam brashtam kuru madagya

Translation :-

Parvati says to Vishnu “He showed us the way to kill him. The best way to teach him a lesson is by destroying the Pativrata dharma of his wife”.

English translators, mistranslated Pativrata as Chastity or Modesty.

So, How did Vishnu destroy pativrata dharma of Vrinda?

Shiva Purana, yuddha khanda 23rd chapter explains it.

First Vishnu created an illusion to Vrinda that her husband (Jalandhar )was killed and later restored to life by him at the request of Vrinda. At that movement, the actual Jalandhar lost his power because Vrinda's pativrata shakti is not acting as an Armour to him and eventually killed by Shiva.

But Vrinda embraced the fake Jalandhar as her husband in illusion and started roaming with him in the forests for few days.Everything she experiencing that time was just illusion.

Shiva Purana, Yuddha Khanda, 23rd chapter slokas 39–40

39th sloka in Sanskrit :-

Atha prasan hridaya sa hi samajat ichaya

Reme tad vanamadhyastha tadyukta bahuvasaran

Hindi Translation :-

Vah(Vrinda ne) prasann chith se kaam ka uday hone par us van ke madhya me hi uske saat bahut dino tak Vihar karthi Rahi.

Here prasann chith means happiness or blissful, Kaam ka means desire but in English they mistranslated kaam as lust.

Vihar = ghumna (hindi) = to roam or excursion in English

So, the exact English translation will be :-

“Vrinda with the desire of feeling happiness or blissfulness, roamed with him in the forests for several days”.

40th sloka :- In Sanskrit

Kadachit suratasyamate dristva vishnum tameva hi

Nirbhatsrya trodhasamyukta vrinda vachanambravit

Hindi Translation :-

Yek baar vihaar ke anth (end of excursion) usko vishnu ke roop mein jaankar krodh se yukth hokar fatkarthi huyi vrinda yaha vachan boli.

Here the word Surata has been mistranslated as sexual intercousre in English. But in Hindi,Surata mean Raman.

Raman = vihar karna (to roam happily or excursion), man prasann karne ki prakriya (process of making mind happy), enjoy etc…

But for the English authors happiness or pleasantness means SEX. 39th sloka clearly says she roamed with him in the forests.

So, in 40th sloka surata + anth = vihar karna(excursion)+ anth (end).

In the 40th sloka Suratasyamate = at the end of excursion.

So, the English translation of 40th sloka becomes like this :-

“ Once after the end of excursion, she thought him to be Vishnu and she angrily says these words “.

In the 41st and later slokas,Vrinda accused Vishnu for her husband's death and she immolated herself and reached Vaikunta “.

Later, river Gandaki was made from her ashes and Tulasi plant (Holy Basil) was made from her hair.

So, where did r@pe or sex you're accusing happen? The actual Sanskrit word for the sexual intercourse is “Maithun”. In 39th and 40th slokas there is no word called Maithun.

The Sanskrit word for r@pe is “Balatkar “. Show me the word Balatkar in any sloka.

Comment: You claim 'chastity' is not a good translation of 'pativrata' (perhaps a more accurate one would be 'faithfulness to the husband'), but you never provide one yourself. What does it mean then? Also, what is your evidence for claiming that "everything she was experiencing that time was just illusion"? The text doesn't say anything like that. Finally, 'surata' is translated to 'sexual intercourse' in many other Sanskrit texts, in which there is no ambiguity to what it means.